How can I convert a vector of Variables and a vector of scalars to Expressions in cvxr?
I think this is trivial, but I'm stumbling over my lack of knowledge about both R and CVXR. I have something like, except with many more variables:
x <- Variable(1)
y <- Variable(1)
z <- Variable(1)
vars <- c(x, y, z)
scalars <- c(3, 4, 5)

What I'd like to do is Maximize a function that sums each variable multiplied by its scalar, like this:
objective <- Maximize(sum(3 * x, 4 * y, 5 * z))

Naively, I'd like to do construct expressions somehow like Maximize(sum(vars * scalars)) but that doesn't work. Is there any way to construct the objective function's Expressions on the fly from vectors?

I know this seems obvious and maybe trivial, but I just entered your initial question into chatgpt and the answer was quite exhaustive. I am not going to post i there since that is ground for account termination. But just try it. Fiddle with the code and see, if it does not help you along.

Ah, that helps. Looks like I'm looking for the multiply function. Or at least that seems most promising.
